# Job Title for a person who writes tests and manages source code?

Tags: startup, title

I run a small startup team and we are about to hire a person who would hopefully take care of testing (writes and executes) and manage our git source code (like a project manager). What do you think would be the best job title to describe this position?

Comment: whats wrong with Project Manager?

Comment: Project managers should be kept as far away from git as possible :-) Let the technical team manage git.

Comment: while I disagree with the overly smug attitude of @Phil (git is hard only clever IT ppl can use it ho ho ho) I do wonder about the wisdom of describing a project manager as one who "manages a git repository". You imagine that "tester" would be a more normal description here...

Comment: You have two non-overlapping sets of responsibility there - there isn't really a job title that covers both. Either go with the "more important" one or just call it "Tester and Project Manager". Although a project manager doesn't really manage code and, as a developer, it's not really clear to me why you need someone to specifically manage your source code (it really makes more sense to have one / all of your developers take responsibility for it). Also, questions asking what the best job title would be are a bit too opinion-based and not really useful to others to be on topic here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "manage our git source code"? It could very well be within the responsibilities of whomever is testing the code to pull that code from git and also tell people when they've messed something up. If it goes beyond that in that your developers are messing up git enough (or just don't use it for whatever reason) that it appears to make sense to hire someone to take responsibility for that, your problem is your developers, not a lack of one person to oversee everything.

Comment: Ok, the most important responsibility will be the testing. Based on the comments I think I need to move the responsibility for the source code to the developers.

Comment: What does _"manage our git source code"_ mean?

Comment: If "managing" the source code, means tagging releases and approving deployments, then "release manager" or "release engineer" are titles I've heard.  If this person also does testing, you can say "Testing and release engineer".

Comment: Use [Software Wizard](https://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?project=Macintosh&story=Software_Wizard.txt) like Andy Hertzfeld did when Apple was a startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to handle git is that the developers manage the source code. Not anyone outside the development team. You will have someone responsible for setting up the repository, setting up permissions, making backups etc., but managing the source code is purely the developers' business.

In a very small company, you might have one person responsible for QA (Quality Assurance) and general IT.

Answer (score 0):

Tester would be my choice.

You can train someone to use git, it's not hard just very dull.

Is harder to train a tester. So find a good tester, and then just train them to use git commands. Although why your developers don't know how to use it is a little odd...

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I will do. The responsibility for the source code management will be the developers.

Answer (score 0):

"Test engineer" sounds like a good start. It's basicly the default title for someone writing and executing software tests.

If you want it to sound *very important* you could go for "quality management officer", but that title usually involves making sure that a product meets quality standards set by norms, standards and laws (for example in medical products).

In your case "code quality manager" could be a compromize between the non-technical "quality management officer" and the more technical "test engineer".